# pip install web3 error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3.py, python, visual-studio-code

Below is my detailed query:

When i try to import web3, solcx, & dotenv, it gives me an error saying: Import "web3" could not be resolved Import "solcx" could not be resolved Import "dotenv" could not be resolved. I even tried copy pasting the full code to ensure there isn't any error in the code, but i guess there's something else out of the way. I tried what internet suggested me (such as installing Visual Studio Community 2022, VSBuild Tools 2022 with the C++ fearures, checking different Python interpreters available in VSCode, etc), but so far did not prove to be helpful.

When i do pip install web3, i get error :

```
"... C:\Users\ashvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lru-dict

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure."
```

And when i run the program code, the detailed Terminal Output appears as:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ashvi/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/sam", line 3, in <module>
    from web3 import Web3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web3' "
```

Code link: https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/web3_py_simple_storage/blob/main/deploy.py

Python version: I had Python 3.10, then upon someone's recommendation, changed it to 3.9, and recently to 3.8.10.

Python Interpreter in VSCode: using the recommended one by VSCode, i.e. 3.8.10 64-bit.

Web3 version: I had 5.29.1, but changed it to 5.24.0 after coming across this article: https://medium.com/@cromewar/the-mighty-cytools-error-at-web3-smart-contract-development-with-brownie-63335d50f230

So can someone please be kind enough to help me out here?
Thank you.

Comment: Try pip3 install instead? Try following the tutorial exactly

Comment: Windows usually doesn't have the best support in blockchain. I'd suggest to try using linux inside a VM or installing WSL2.

Comment: [This is a duplicate of this StackoverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory).